# My number is showing weird values when using Math.floor() or .toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an incremental game and have come across an issue I just can not seem to fix:

This is my pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const stats = {
    timePlayed: 0
  }

  const atoms = {
    amount: 0,
    increment: 0.001,
    max: 10
  }

  return { atoms, stats }
})
```

And this is my gameLoop file:

```
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'

const user = useUserStore()

let lastTime = null
let timeTotal = 0

setInterval(function gameLoop() {
  const time = performance.now()
  if (lastTime === null) {
    lastTime = time
  }
  const timeDelta = time - lastTime
  timeTotal += timeDelta
  lastTime = time
  updateGame(timeDelta, timeTotal)
}, 1000 / 60)

function updateGame(timeDelta, timeTotal) {
  user.atoms.amount += user.atoms.increment * timeDelta
  user.stats.timePlayed = Math.floor(timeTotal / 1000)
}
```

My issue is that I would like to display the number as a value without any decimals or a value with a maximum of 2 decimals.

When using:

```
function updateGame(timeDelta, timeTotal) {
  user.atoms.amount += Math.floor(user.atoms.increment * timeDelta)
  user.stats.timePlayed = Math.floor(timeTotal / 1000)
}
```

I just get a 0 displayed that jumps to random values seemingly at random intervals (sometimes 5 seconds other times even 20 seconds and ONLY while I'm not on the games tab)

However when using:

```
function updateGame(timeDelta, timeTotal) {
  user.atoms.amount += (user.atoms.increment * timeDelta).toFixed(2)
  user.stats.timePlayed = Math.floor(timeTotal / 1000)
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: My games display of resources]

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns a string, not a number, so the addition operators will do string concatenation, not numeric addition.

Comment: Try this instead: `Math.round(timeTotal / 1000).toFixed(1)`

Comment: @Tim How would that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

When using to fixed, it returns a string, which explains why your second solution contains a large amount of seemingly random numbers. You cannot use toFixed() for math. To convert it back to a float you could use something like

```
parseFloat((user.atoms.increment * timeDelta).toFixed(2))
```

or even better

```
Math.round(user.atoms.increment * timeDelta * 100) / 100
```

However

When calculating the amount of atoms and rounding it beforehand, you are losing accuracy by trying to round before you add to current atoms. 0.001 * timeDelta will produce a very small number, much smaller than 2 decimal places, so why not just `user.atoms.amount += user.atoms.increment * timeDelta` and round it when it needs to be displayed to the user.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer however when using the Math.round method I am still getting like 8 decimal places and regarding the pinia store there are 2 ways of setting them up. There are setup stores (the way I did it) and option stores (the way you did it).

Comment: This is probably due to the += continuing to add the decimals over and over, so you may want to include user.atoms.amount in the rounding as well.

Comment: Ok now it is actually rounded to 2 decimals but now it wont go higher than 0.02 lol

Comment: Your increment is very small so the 100 I had probably should be something like 1000 or even 10000 to ensure you don't lose the values to the rounding. You're working with very small numbers here and you need to account for that.

Comment: On second thought why are you even concerned with rounding? It seems like the atoms increases linearly with time, and increases by a very small amount, so why don't you just let the float be a float and just += user.atoms.increment * timeDelta. Worry about the rounding when you display it to the user.

Comment: I believe the issue is that I am already displaying the atoms automatically using {{user.atoms.amount}} in my .vue component and because of that I need the number to also be correct internally because whatever the number is internally get's automatically displayed by vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257260/discussion-between-tristan-lovasz-and-joseph-carpenter).